# Hbox has child Buttons , how to grab and addlisteners to them?

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

to start here's the FXML, a simple Hbox with Buttons inside :

```
        <HBox fx:id="hboxOfCategories" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="10.0">
           <children>
              <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Boissons" />
              <Button layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Burger" />
              <Button layoutX="102.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Tacos" />
              <Button layoutX="378.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Pizza" />
              <Button layoutX="194.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Baguette Farcie" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" />
              <Button layoutX="286.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Souflee" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
```

i saved his content inside an Observable list , it had to be type Node because the .getChildren() method returns something that's type Node :

fxml controller code :

```
@FXML
    private void initialize(){

    ObservableList<Node> hboxButtons = hboxOfCategories.getChildren();

}
```

How can i grab those buttons and add a listener to them that triggers when the buttons are clicked ?
something like this :

```
hboxofCategories.getchildren().addlistener(e -> {
doEpicStuff();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
for(Node button : hboxOfCategories.getChildren())
    {
        ((Button)button).setOnAction(a -> {
                System.out.println("Pressed : "+ ((Button)button).getText());
            });
    }
```

Output :

[image]

**EDIT** :

Here is how you can get the index :

```
for(int i=0;i<hboxOfCategories.getChildren().size();i++)
{
    Button button=(Button)hboxOfCategories.getChildren().get(i);
    int index=i;
    button.setOnAction(a->
                       {
                           System.out.println("Name : "+button.getText()+" | Index : "+index);
                       });
}
```

Comment: Follow up on the same question : 
let's say i want to get the index of the clicked button inside the Hbox ?

for example : 
 <hbox>
           <button text="pizza" />
           <button text="Burger" />
</hbox>

Here's clicking pizza : would return : 0 
Here's clicking Burger : would return : 1